# What is cause of ruby: No such file of directory -- passenger (LoadError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

A month ago we completed testing a standard Rails Cloud Server install process.
We installed more than a dozen Cloud Servers running Rails applications. They we took a break from installing new applications.  (all that to say the process was solid)

Today we built a new cloud server and installed one of the Rails applications we have previously installed successfully.  We followed the same documented process at at the very end, when issuing the passenger start command

```
rvm-exec ruby-1.9.3-p286 ruby -S passenger start -p 4000 -e production > /dev/null & disown
```

we received this error message:

> ruby: No such file or directory -- passenger (LoadError)

we have been searching and cannot find this error mentioned anywhere on the net.
Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration we determined the passenger gem had to be installed (again) in the global gemset.  We knew the passenger gem was installed, but it was not found in any of the gemsets.  Installing passenger explicitly in the global gemset resolved the problem.